# Loop through $_POST array item_nameX (Dynamically Add Number to End of Variable Name)

Tags: php, for-loop, paypal, foreach, eclipse-pdt

UPDATE: THIS IS SOLVED AND THE WORKING CODE IS PASTED IN THE BOTTOM OF THIS POST. I KEEP THE ORIGINAL POST SO OTHERS CAN READ AND FOLLOW.

I have had a big problem going Live with PayPal but think I have found the issue.

Look at this screenshot, it is from the pdt.php where customers are redirected to after purchase and it is a real one, did with a real visa: http://snag.gy/5XCvA.jpg

I have printed the whole TX-id at the top for debugging and here I can see that item_number1=54, quantity1=1 and item_name1=Introduktionsföreläsning.

The problem is that these do not show under Produkt, ID and Antal(Product, Id and Quantity) which is used to be presented to the customer. This is because I have the variables set like this:

```
$item_number = $response[item_number];
$item_name = $response[item_name];
$qty = $response[quantity];
```

and they never get anymore than just item_number, when they need to get "++:ed" to item_number1, item_number2 etc for every product.

I have tried to do a lot of changes, for example:

```
for($idx = 1; $idx < $count; $idx ++) 
        {
            //$item_name .=$idx ++;
            //$item_name = $item_name++;
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Produkt: ".$item_name."</div>\n");
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>ID: ".$item_number."</div>\n");
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Antal: ".$qty."</div>\n");
            echo ("<br />");
        }
```

Where the outcommented lines is where I try to append a number to item_name but I just get "1" or nothing at all as an answer when I need it to be item_name1 and so on.

Here is my PDT script: 
But im pretty sure it can be fixed in this area of code: http://pastebin.com/L2nyT9q7

```
$array_keys = array_keys($response);
    $count = 1;
    foreach($array_keys as $element) 
    {
        if (!strncmp('item_number', $element, strlen('item_number')))
            $count++;       
    }
        for($idx = 1; $idx < $count; $idx ++) 
        {
            if (isset($string1) && 'item_name' != null) 
            {
            //$item_name .=$idx ++;
            //$item_name = $item_name++;
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Produkt: ".$item_name."</div>\n");
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>ID: ".$item_number."</div>\n");
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Antal: ".$qty."</div>\n");
            echo ("<br />");
            }
        }
```

Also: I have read on some forums with people with similar problems and they have gotten replies to use item_nameX as the variable name and I have tried that too, without any other result. If I hardcode `$item_number = $response[item_number1];` <- where I specify the 1 I will get the correct details. I have tested that.

WORKING CODE:

```
$array_keys = array_keys($response);
    $count = 1;
    $i = 1;

    foreach($array_keys as $element) 
    {
        if (!strncmp('item_number', $element, strlen('item_number')))
            $count++;   
    }
        for($idx = 1; $idx < $count; $idx ++ & $i++) 
        {   
            $item_number = $response[item_number . $i];
            $item_name = $response[item_name . $i];
            $qty = $response[quantity . $i];        
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Produkt: ".$item_name."</div>\n");
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>ID: ".$item_number."</div>\n");
            echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Antal: ".$qty."</div>\n");
            echo ("<br />");
        }
```

Comment: (edited) You have something bad with logic there: 'item_name' is a string, so it's never null. And the code overall is extremely hard to read because of style.

Comment: Yes that is true, thanks. But I dont think it even served a function, I deleted it and I have the same result. Only name showing, but that indicates that it still can find the name, but still the item_name is just item_name and not item_name1 for example. Ill update the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten and cleaned up some of your code. **This is untested**, but hopefully it will get you going in the right direction.

```
$product_ids = array(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,33,41,43,45,47,49,51,54,55,57,58);
   $msg = '';
   $num_items = 0;
   if ( array_key_exists('num_cart_items', $response) )
      $num_items = intval($response['num_cart_items']);

   if ( !empty($num_items) )
   {
      $string1 = 'item_name';
      $string2 = 'item_number';
      $firstname = $response['first_name'];
      $lastname = $response['last_name'];
      $total = $response['mc_gross'];

      for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_items; $i++)
      {
         $item_number = $response['item_number'.$i];
         $item_name = $response['item_name'.$i];
         $qty = $response['quantity'.$i];
         $id = $response['item_number'.$i];
         // do something with these vars since they change every iteration through the loop and only exist within the scope of the loop.

         if ( in_array($item_number, $product_ids) ) {
            $msg = '<p><div id="bold">Produkter tillgängliga för nerladdning/lyssning</div></p><br>';
         }
      }
   }

   echo '
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="welcomeText">Tack för ditt köp!</div>
      <div class="abouttext3">Har du köpt produkter som ska laddas ned, laddar du ned dem NU till din dator. <br> Du har endast möjlighet att ladda ned från just den här sidan.<br>
          Stanna kvar på sidan tills du laddat ned ALLT du köpt. <br>OBS! Om du stänger ned sidan har du inte möjlighet att komma tillbaka till den.<br>
          Har du köpt en lyssning av ”Guidning till förlåtelse” lyssnar du på den HÄR och NU. <br> Var kvar på sidan tills du lyssnat klart. <br> OBS!
          Om du stänger ned sidan har du inte möjlighet att komma tillbaka till den. <br />
          Har du köpt varor som levereras med Posten, skickas de så snart som möjligt från oss. <br> Allra senast inom en vecka.
      </div>
      <div class="abouttext2">Vi önskar Dig en bra dag. <br>
         Välkommen tillbaka till energyshop.se när du vill!
      </div>'
      . $msg;  // If item_number matches any product that is for download/listetning, then print this headline
```

Comment: Yep! I just on my own realized that I had been trying to use: $item_number = $response['item_number'].$i; instead of $item_number = $response['item_number'.$i]; where the $i is INSIDE of the []. Silly me. Thanks a lot, the rest of the code is also very helpful and I think I will manage to sort this out now.

Comment: I did it! I didnt use all ur code, but what I needed to gt it done. Im sure it could be better, but its working and its by my hands so im happy! :) Updated code.